# How to fix php foreach in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: admin/v_pembelian.php

Line Number: 80

```
  <tbody>
                    <?php $i = 1; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items){ ?>
                    <?php echo form_hidden($i.'[rowid]', $items['rowid']); ?>
                    <tr>
                         <td><?=$items['id'];?></td>
                         <td><?=$items['name'];?></td>
                         <td style="text-align:center;"><?=$items['satuan'];?></td>
                         <td style="text-align:right;"><?php echo number_format($items['price']);?></td>
                         <td style="text-align:right;"><?php echo number_format($items['harga']);?></td>
                         <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo number_format($items['qty']);?></td>
                         <td style="text-align:right;"><?php echo number_format($items['subtotal']);?></td>
                         <td style="text-align:center;"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'admin/pembelian/remove/'.$items['rowid'];?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-close"></span> Batal</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $i++; ?>
                  <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
```

I want to display data on items that have been inserted

Comment: Looks like `$this->cart->contents()` is not iterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am not positive of the structure of `$this->cart->contents()`, casting this object to an array like so: `(array)$this->cart->contents()` will probably give the results you are expecting;

```php
 <tbody>
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach ((array)$this->cart->contents() as $items){ ?>
    <?php echo form_hidden($i.'[rowid]', $items['rowid']); ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?=$items['id'];?></td>
        <td>
            <?=$items['name'];?></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <?=$items['satuan'];?></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">
            <?php echo number_format($items['price']);?></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">
            <?php echo number_format($items['harga']);?></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <?php echo number_format($items['qty']);?></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">
            <?php echo number_format($items['subtotal']);?></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <a href="
<?php echo base_url().'admin/pembelian/remove/'.$items['rowid'];?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-close"></span> Batal</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```